# How to fetch Firebase Json api, I got response and i can consol log it, But the problem with FlatList

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, axios, react-native-flatlist

I want to fetch a API which is a Firebase JSON response

Here is the URL : https://learn-efc13-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/products.json

**This is my Code**:

```
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    Get();
  }, []);

  function Get() {
    axios
      .get("https://learn-efc13-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/products.json")
      .then(async function (response) {
        setData(response.data);
        console.log(response.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.error(err));
  }
```

**Here is my FlatList**:

```
     <FlatList
        data={data.products}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
        renderItem={({ item }) => <Text>{item.age}{item.name}</Text>}
      />
```

My problem is here I got the response, **but I can not display it in the Text component**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had a look at your JSON endpoint and I can't see a property called `products`. It also looks like the data returned from the endpoint is an object. `FlatList` expects an array to be passed into the `data` prop (see example here https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist).

I'm going to assume that this is why the FlatList component isn't returning anything.

So to correct this, you need to make sure `products` is present in the response from your API and you need to make sure that the data that you are passing into data prop for `<FlatList />` is an array.

On a side note, I noticed that you were using `async` within the callback of the promise from `axios.get()` but it doesn't look like you are using `await` within the function so you probably don't need it.